# WPF Rich text box underline

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have strange problem with my richtextbox.
I want to detect when text is Bold, Italic etc.

E.g

```
   if (richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty).ToString() == "Italic")  // Pochylenie
            {
                heremycode
            }
```

If we use

`MessageBox(richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty).ToString());`

I get Italic. I want do exacly the same with underline and strikethrough, because I can't use

`TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty.ToString()`,

because i get only name of method i think? Nothink like "italic", or "bold" just "FontStyleProperty".

```
private void richTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        if (richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty).ToString() == "Italic"
        {
            backgroundP.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            backgroundP.Fill = Brushes.LawnGreen;
            p = true;
        }

        TextRange selectionRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Selection.Start, richTextBox.Selection.End);

            if (selectionRange.GetPropertyValue(Underline.TextDecorationsProperty).Equals(TextDecorations.Underline))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wow We did it :)");
                backgroundUnderline.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            }
    }
```

And XAML Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Center" Margin="10,231,10,10">
            <Rectangle Fill="#B2F4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Margin="1,0,-1,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="labelNotepad" Content="Notepad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="385" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FFC1FCFF" FontSize="21.333" Height="56" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1,0,0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"/>
            <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Margin="1,58,0,0" FontSize="16" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#7FFFFFFF" SelectionChanged="richTextBox_SelectionChanged">
                <FlowDocument/>
            </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: what is the result from your try ? An Exception or a Empty string etc. ?

Comment: In messageBox i have only somethink like TextAligmentPropety, name of method u know, in the other one i have result like "left", "bold", etc.

Comment: can you add this to your question and a screenshot or something else that will help

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
TextRange selectionRange = new TextRange(RichTextControl.Selection.Start, RichTextControl.Selection.End);

        if (selectionRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) == TextDecorations.Underline)
        {
        }
```

this should work, you get only the Object name beacause you don´t set the dependency property what you want to have as a string. The decoration can be Underline etc you must declarate what you want to check

Comment: It doesn't work i tried this but it doesn't matter what i do ( select text, or just click in RichTextBox ) my messageBox is silent :D

Comment: mhm then post more from your code then i can take a look over it

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of your code because SeeuD1's suggestion should work.  However, it will only work if the entire selection is underlined.

If you need to see if there is ANY underlined text in the selection, not ONLY, then you need to check all the inline objects in the selection.

In this example I will only check paragraphs in your FlowDocument:

```
        foreach (var block in RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Where(x => selection.Start.CompareTo(x.ContentEnd) < 0 && selection.End.CompareTo(x.ContentStart) > 0))
        {
            var paragraph = block as Paragraph;
            if (paragraph != null)
            {
                foreach (var selectedInline in paragraph.Inlines.Where(x => selection.Start.CompareTo(x.ContentEnd) < 0 && selection.End.CompareTo(x.ContentStart) > 0))
                {
                    if (selectedInline.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) == TextDecorations.Underline)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wow We did it :)");
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```